# How to Pass API Response to Azure SQL Table via Stored Procedure

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a Azure Data Factory pipeline that uploads data to Salesforce and then gets the response back to Azure Data Factory. I am trying to get the response from the failed job and store in my failed records table in Azure SQL. I am using Stored Procedure activity to pass on the values to the table. The issue I am having is that the stored Procedure activity is getting the correct input for response but when it passes the value to SQL it just insert ".

[image]

[image]

[image]

I previously had the failed_records_details column set as Varchar(max) and then tried to change it to NText and see if SQL would accept the string value passes on from the API response. But I haven't had any luck so far. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are there other columns inserted successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
OP changed his table structure to varchar(max) and it worked.

---

After many tests, I found the answer. I used OPENJSON to process in stored procedure.

1. This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product](
    [PRODUCT_ID] [int] NULL,
    [PRODUCT_TYPE] [int] NULL,
    [PRODUCT_NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PRODUCT_TITLE] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [PRODUCT_PIC] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CREATE_TIME] [datetime] NULL,
    [UPDATE_TIME] [datetime] NULL,
    [PRODUCT_INTRO] [text] NULL,
    [PRODUCT_FEATURE_ID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [PRODUCT_PARAM] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

2. This is my  API response:

```
{
    "productId": 2,
    "productTypeId": 2,
    "productName": "AD2",
    "productTitle": "TopAir AD215-1000A",
    "productPic": "/img/productPic/1593684705859user.jpg",
    "createTime": "2020-06-05 09:17:31",
    "updateTime": "2020-06-05 09:17:31",
    "productFeatureId": "",
    "productParam": "/img/productPic/param/1593685548627a32415ca9a21f6f9a1d99b2731f224b5d319c424.jpg",
    "productIntro": "",
    "productType": null,
...
```

3. This is my stored procedure, the api request as a string type input parameter.

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProduct] @product NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS  

BEGIN TRY 
        INSERT INTO dbo.product(PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_TYPE,PRODUCT_NAME,PRODUCT_TITLE,PRODUCT_PIC,CREATE_TIME,UPDATE_TIME,PRODUCT_INTRO,PRODUCT_FEATURE_ID,PRODUCT_PARAM)
                SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@product)
                    WITH(
                        PRODUCT_ID int '$.productId',
                        PRODUCT_TYPE int '$.productTypeId',
                        PRODUCT_NAME varchar(50) '$.productName',
                        PRODUCT_TITLE varchar(255) '$.productTitle',
                        PRODUCT_PIC varchar(255) '$.productPic',
                        CREATE_TIME datetime '$.createTime',
                        UPDATE_TIME datetime '$.updateTime',
                        PRODUCT_INTRO varchar(255) '$.productIntro',
                        PRODUCT_FEATURE_ID varchar(255) '$.productFeatureId',
                        PRODUCT_PARAM varchar(255) '$.productParam'

                    )
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE ( )   
END CATCH
;
```

4. Add dynamic content `@string(activity('Web1').output)`. After repeated testing, here we must convert API response from object type to string type.
   [image]
5. This is the input of the Stored procedure1 activity.
   [image]
6. The debugging results are as follows:
   [image]

I can see the API response was inserted into the table.

Comment: Thanks Anuj for the response, but I think in my case I need to escape the \" which appears after every word. I think Azure ignores everything after \ so that's the reason only " gets inserted in the table. I have tried to use @replace expression in the dynamic content but it doesn't work either. Is there anything else you think would work?

Comment: Hi @Mariya  We don’t need to remove this escape character. Using openjson in the stored procedure will automatically ignore these escape characters. And it is impossible to remove escape characters in dynamic expressions.

Comment: But from what I understand the value that you have is in Key:Value format, but the reponse from my API is in a string format, not sure if openJSON will work in this case as well. Sorry for my ignorance, I am new to Data Factory and writing stored procedure so it is taking some time for me to understand all this

Comment: Hi @Mariya Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Joseph the openjson did not work for me since the API value is not enclosed in json format. I had to change my table structure to varchar(max) and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi@Mariya Great, you solved the problem. I've updated my answer. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. :)